# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-11

I am encounted with this Crash on Android 11 devices. Below is the mentioned log which I received from the device. I am not able to debug/relate this issue. Could someone please help me to trace and fixed this issue.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
 at android.app.ContextImpl.getDisplay (ContextImpl.java:2497)
 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDisplay (ContextWrapper.java:1015)
 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDisplay (ContextWrapper.java:1015)
 at android.widget.Editor.getDisplayHeightPixels (Editor.java:9669)
 at android.widget.Editor.access$3300 (Editor.java:209)
 at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.clipVertically (Editor.java:6956)
 at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updatePosition (Editor.java:6936)
 at android.widget.Editor$PositionListener.onPreDraw (Editor.java:3660)
 at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw (ViewTreeObserver.java:1093)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3194)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2046)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:8349)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1058)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:880)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:813)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1043)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:236)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7861)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:600)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wich Crash? I see no exceptions in the log.

Comment: I have updated the stack trace